# Voice recognition from exist audio file

Tags: android, voice-recognition, voice

**How to provide voice recognition compare from exist audio file.**

For example ;

Have a **voice1.mp3** (include "hello") and i want to user try to say "**Hello**" and compare between voice and audio file.

I research RecognizerIntent class but don't find any tips. Can anyone please guide me.

Comment: Please tell me if you found the solution, i have the same issue